# How to get the value of cookie in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I have created 3 cookies:

- cookieone: 123
- cookietwo: 234
- cookiethree: 345

How to use if condition to check the value of cookie? something like

```
$val = "234";
if(coockieone = $val) {
    echo "its a right way";
}
else {
    echo "its a wrong way";
}
```

Comment: First you have to get the value from the cookies, and it's not as trivial as you seem to think, secondly you have to compare values with `==` or `===` to see if they match

Comment: I'd suggest doing a basic course in Javascript and PHP to get familiar with the syntax and semantics. Then (after you figure out how to get a cookie) this problem becomes trivial.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if($_COOKIE['cookieone'] === $value){
    // do what you want
  }
```